# Timestamp when function in script runs

Tags: scripting, google-sheets, timestamp, cell

This is not a duplicate to the other questions where people are trying to update a cell in a google sheet with a time-stamp when another cell is updated....

This question is about how to get a time-stamp in a google sheet cell when a *function in a script runs*.

So, how do I get a cell in my worksheet updated with the time-stamp of when a function in my script last ran?

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that takes care of the timestamp and call this function from your script function. Something like

```
function yourFunction() {
//your code here
setTimeStamp()
}

function setTimeStamp() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('name_of_sheet')
.getRange('A1').setValue(new Date())
}
```

Change sheet name and range to suit. 
Note: in case you are working with a script that is not container bound, change  SpreadsheetApp.getActive() to SpreadsheetApp.openById() and provide the ID of the spreadsheet as a paramater.

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm. I modified your function to be specific to a sheet id, as you suggested.